# Stored procedure that does not filter if a variable is null

Tags: sql, crystal-reports-2008

I have this stored procedure that I want to use for my SAP crystal report.

```
SELECT
    t0.DocNum AS ReceiptNo, t2.DocEntry AS InvoiceNo, 
    t0.DocDate, t1.CheckAct,
    t1.CheckNum, t3.AcctName, 
    CASE 
        WHEN (t0.CardName IS NULL) THEN t0.Address
                                   ELSE t0.CardName
    END AS CustName,
    CASE 
        WHEN ((t1.CheckNum IS NULL OR t1.CheckNum = 0)
               AND t0.TrsfrRef IS NULL) THEN 'Cash'
        WHEN (t1.CheckNum > 0
               AND t0.TrsfrRef IS NULL) THEN 'Cheque'
        ELSE 'Transfer'
    END AS PayType, 
    CASE 
        WHEN (t1.CheckNum > 0 AND t0.TrsfrRef IS NULL) THEN t1.CheckSum
        ELSE t0.DocTotal
    END AS DocTotal
FROM
    ORCT t0
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    RCT1 t1 ON t1.docnum = t0.docnum
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    RCT2 t2 ON t0.DocEntry = t2.DocNum
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    OACT t3 ON t1.CheckAct = t3.AcctCode
WHERE
    t0.DocDate BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate
    AND t0.Canceled = 'N'
    AND t3.AcctCode = @Account
```

On the last line, I have declared a variable `@Account` that filters results by account number. I want my report to work such that if an account is not selected(null), results of all account numbers are returned.

How do I achieve this?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to the end

```
or t3.AcctCode is null
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want the last clause to be effectively omitted if `@Account` is null.  If so, then try this:

```
... AND t0.Canceled = 'N' AND
(@Account IS NULL OR t3.AcctCode = @Account)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `IF ELSE` e.g.

```
IF @Account IS NULL
    BEGIN
        --Your Query without "AND t3.AcctCode = @Account"
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- Your Query
    END
```

You could also change your last line to:

```
AND (t3.AcctCode = @Account OR @Account IS NULL)
```